# I need help finding the Volume using the Washer method

Tags: calculus

I've been stuck trying to understand what exactly is going on with this question. I've been unable to identify what the radius is and the section that is being revolved around using the Washer method.

**The question is:** **Find the volume of each solid that results from revolving the described region about the stated axis, using the washer method.**

The region bounded by $ f(x)= x^{(3)} $, the line $ y=1 $, and the y-axis, revolved about the line $ y=2 $.

Normally, questions revolving around the x or y-axis are simpler and I'm wondering what the difference is for these types of problems.

Comment: What if the region is now bounded by $f(x)=x^{3}-2$, the line $y=-1$ and the $y$-axis, and is now revolving about the $x$-axis? Do you know how to find the volume?

Comment: You know the boundary of the region along y-axis which is $y = 1$ and $y = x^3$. Now for lower and upper bound of radius of revolution, what is the distance of $y = 1$ from $y = 2$ and what is the distance of curve $y = x^3$ from $y = 2$?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out with this description.